# “the put-downs as opposed to the come-ons”

Tags: phrase-meaning

> The most common type of sexual harassment is gender harassment, the report finds. Such behaviour conveys the impression that women do not belong in the workplace or do not merit respect — **“the put-downs as opposed to the come-ons”**, Johnson says. These actions might seem minor but can seriously affect the person targeted. She says that they also set the stage for the other types of sexual harassment: unwanted sexual attention and sexual coercion.

Source: [Nature](https://www.nature.com/articles/d41586-018-05404-6)

For the phrase “the put-downs as opposed to the come-ons”, I understand "put-down" as saying "put your work down and leave, you don't belong to here" and "come-on" as "continue your work, you deserve respect."  Am I on the right track?

Comment: Have you looked up '[put-down](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/put-down)' and '[come-on](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/come-on)' in a dictionary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A "put-down" is a negative, insulting or disparaging comment.

A "come-on" is sexual comment, or "flirt".

Both "put-downs" and "come-ons" can be a form of sexual harrassment.

Comment: Thank you. What I don't really understand is the use of "as opposed to" if both put-down and come-on are not good things.

Comment: It says the *the most common type of harassment is "put-downs", not "come-ons"*  So they are opposite in one way: If you give someone a put-down you say "You're ugly". If you give someone a come-on you say "You're pretty".  But they both "bad" in different ways.